Working with Tensors
For a general rank-5 tensor $T_{abcde}$ I need to compute $T_{(abcde)}-T_{a(bcde)}$ where $()$ are symmetry brackets. What Mathematica code can one write to achieve this?

Did you searched anywhere? What did you find? What have you tried? Why did that work?

$T_{abcd}$ isn’t “rank-5”.

@Ghoster, thanks, I corrected it.

In addition to rhermans comment: 1. What's the expected output? 2. Have you checked the new-in-14.1 ArraySymbol (don't miss Details section of the document)? Please clarify your question according to the comments, the question will be reopened once it becomes clear enough.

By changing $T_{abcd}$ to $T_{abcde}$ you invalidated Michael Weyrauch’s answer from five days ago. That’s not nice.

As was noted in a comment your tensors are rank 4 only, but anyway you might go along the following example which determines the difference of two tensors, one symmetrized in all 4 slots and the other one in the last three slots only. Then you obtain their difference as t1-t2. The Normal is needed in order to convert to a standard array. Simplify is sometimes needed to clean up the result.
t1 = Symmetrize[Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}], Symmetric[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]
t2 = Symmetrize[Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}], Symmetric[{2, 3, 4}]]
t1 - t2 // Normal // Simplify

